# Clarification on variance and expectation of Y value

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a random variable where

$P(X = 1) = \frac13$

$P(X = 2) = \frac13$

$P(X = 3) = \frac13$

Let $Y = (X − 1)(X − 2)$ be another random variable that depends on $X$.

What is $E(Y)$?

I calculated that $E(X)$= 2

Then wouldn't $E(Y) = (E(X) -1)(E(X)-2)$?

My answer ended up being $0$, but the actual answer was given to me as $\frac23$

How am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$E[Y] = {1 \over 3}\underbrace{[(1-1)(1-2)]}_{X = 1} + {1 \over 3}\underbrace{[(2-1)(2-2)]}_{X=2} + {1 \over 3}\underbrace{[(3-1)(3-2)]}_{X=3} = {2 \over 3}$.

Your title mentions *variance*, so:

${\rm Var}[Y] = E[(Y - E[y])^2] \\ = {1 \over 3}[((1-1)(1-2)- 2/3)^2] + {1 \over 3}[((2-1)(2-2)- 2/3)^2] + {1 \over 3}[((3-1)(3-2)- 2/3)^2] \\= {24 \over 27}$.

Expectation is a linear operator, so your product rule is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

> Then wouldn't $E(Y) = (E(X) -1)(E(X)-2)$?

No, the expectation of a product *is not* the product of expectations.

> My answer ended up being 0 , but the actual answer was given to me as $\tfrac 23$

It is.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(Y) ~=~& \mathsf E((X-1)(X-2)) & \neq ~\mathsf E(X-1)~\mathsf E(X-2) \\[1ex] ~=~& \mathsf E(X^2-3X+2) \\[1ex] ~=~& \mathsf E(X^2)-3\,\mathsf E(X)+2 \\[1ex] ~=~& \tfrac 1 3(1^2+2^2+3^2)-\tfrac 33(1+2+3)+2 \\[1ex] ~=~&\frac 2 3\end{align}$$